# Function parameter destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is there a way I can destructure my data in my function arguments?

```
const AgendaItem = ({ item }) => {
  const { venue, organiser, startTime, endTime, description } = item;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Location: {venue}</Text>
      <Text>Consultant: {organiser}</Text>
      <Text>Time: {`${startTime} - ${endTime}`}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description || "None"}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description || "None"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AgendaItem;
```

If I do:

```
const AgendaItem = ({ venue, organiser /*..etc*/ }) => {
```

I get `undefined` when I `return` them.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joj8fc6a/2/

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand you item is an object and have your own properties.

You can do something like this:

```
const AgendaItem = ({ item: { venue, organiser, startTime, endTime, description } }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Location: {venue}</Text>
      <Text>Consultant: {organiser}</Text>
      <Text>Time: {`${startTime} - ${endTime}`}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description || "None"}</Text>
      <Text>Description: {description || "None"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AgendaItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead
`const AgendaItem = ({item: { venue, organiser /*..etc*/ }}) => {`

Answer (score -1):

`const AgendaItem = ({ item }) => { ...`

is the same as

`const AgendaItem = (arg) => { const item = arg.item; ...`

---

So if you do `const AgendaItem = ({ venue, organiser ...etc }) => {` and your object with an `item` attribute is still being passed, then `venue`, `organiser`, and `etc` will correctly be `undfined` since the engine will be looking for those properties in the argument object and not find them.